# Вывод даты на сайт PHP

Tags: php, php7

подскажите пожалуйста, у меня в базе данных есть дата формата *1578237431*. Хочу попытаться вывести ее как человеческое число, попытался использовать ответ с вашего сайта `DATE_FORMAT(dateColumn,'%d/%m/%Y') AS dateColumn`, естественно значение dateColumn изменил на date (название столбца) Но ничего не сработало и код не выводил ничего. Подскажите, может я что то не так делаю? Что мне надо сделать, чтобы при `echo($row['date']);` выводилась дата и в адекватном формате? Спасибо.

P.S Значения `SID='{$steamid['SID']}'` берется раньше, поэтому спрашивать не надо про него

```
<? $sql=$link->query("select * from `ma_violations` WHERE SID='{$steamid['SID']}' order by `id` desc");

# цикл вывода
while($row=$sql->fetch_array()):
  echo "<p></p>";
   echo "<table class='table table-striped'>
      <tr>
        <td><h5>Дата</h5></td><td><h5>";
           echo($row['date']);
   echo "</h5></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td><h5>Нарушение</h5></td>
        <td><h5>";
     echo($row['violation']);
     echo "</h5></td>
      </tr>
    </table>";
    echo "<pre></pre>";
  endwhile;
?>
```

Comment: `echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['date']);`

Comment: Если я поставлю это вместо своей строчки, то дальше код просто валится, на сайте идет ошибка Parse error: syntax error, unexpected ';', expecting ')' in /var/www/u1087147/data/www/u-reborn.site/demo.php on line 157 и код начинает неверно подсвечиваться

Comment: Потому что надо `echo date('d-m-Y', strtotime($row['date']));`
В первом варианте скобочку забыли. ПХП же пишет, что ожидается ')'

Comment: Ввел, вроде вывод заработал, но независимо от того какие числа стоят в базе данных, даже те, которые по факту должны выводится правильно все равно выводится 03:01:00 01-01-1970

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Попробуйте без strtotime

```
date('d-m-Y', $row['date']);
```

Comment: Спасибо, помогло